# why can't i watch this .avi file on my mac (mountain lion)?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, video

I have an .AVI file that I got from a windows machine and i am trying to run it on my mac and i get this error. [image]

The **Tell me more** button doesn't really give me any useful info.

Any suggestions on how to be able to view this from my macbook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OS X doesn't have codecs for AVI files built-in, so you'll either need a plugin to allow QuickTime to play the files directly, or use a different media player that can handle those file types.

For plugins, [Perian](http://perian.org/) has been the go to choice. However it is no longer supported or developed — at the moment it still works well, but as OS X changes, that may no longer be the case.

For third party players, [VLC](https://www.videolan.org/) is pretty robust and will play virtually anything you can find. It has the benefit of ongoing development, but the interface is not always the best (the preferences in particular are pretty convoluted). You can also look at [MplayerX](http://mplayerx.org). There are other options ([Movist](https://code.google.com/p/movist/) and [Niceplayer](https://code.google.com/p/niceplayer/) come to mind), but none seem to have been updated in the past year or more.

Comment: "codecs for AVI files" is too generalised. QuickTime Plug-in 7.7.1, integral to OS X, has three rows for AVI when Safari shows installed plug-ins.